# How to give adhan in newborn baby's ear?

Tags: adhan, baby

In few days, I will become a father and I was wondering how to say adhan in the right way? As new baby has a very delicate ear, so does one whisper, or say it out loud but from a distance? Should it be in both ear or just one? Who should be present at the time of adhan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not necessarily to be a quiet whisper, but it has to be recited through the right ear. And when you're done with adhan, recite the iqama through the baby's left ear.

However, all hadeeths that talked about this matter are considered da'eef (weak), especially the part of iqama. See this https://youtu.be/vXD8qCtdLWo 
[Congrats btw :)]

Comment: Thanks, which adhan should it be, fajr? Or any? Some say fajr. I know there are words to it but why one has precedence over other?

Comment: I believe you say the normal adhan, because it is the original one, as the fajr adhan came later on when the Prophet was asleep, and Bilal RA was waking him up for fajr prayer, but he didn't wake up, so Bilal muttered the extra words in the current fajr adhan, so the Prophet ordered him to add those words.

Comment: I have never heard of them being weak...though they may be. But from a personal experience...I found it one of the most amazing moments of my life, securing my child against Satan so that Satan won't whisper in her ears. Just as we say اعوذ بالله , this is a protection for the child from the beginning.

Comment: Ummm, yea, it sounds nice and more secure for the baby, but if it is a weak hadith, it's better not to do it as a sunnah or order from the Prophet. As it is a great sin to invent stuff in islam without any basis. @asma22

Comment: true...if its a weak hadith then its an invent

Answer (score 3):

Well the ahadith about adhan and iqamah for the new born have many weaknesses, so especially for the iqamah some scholars tend to say the weakness is grave, and one shoould even consider this to be makruh or not mustahab (something not desirable) as quoted in this [Arabic Fatwa](http://web.archive.org/web/20150505071626/http://islamqa.info:80/ar/136088).

Some if not most scholars say that the first thing the new born should hear are these words about the almightiness of Allah (see more interpretation of this [here](http://www.alukah.net/social/0/66637/)), while other scholars say one should do it when the kid got his/her [name](http://www.alifta.net/fatawa/fatawachapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=5229&PageNo=1&BookID=5), so it could be done at the day of 'Aqiqa (~7 days after birth).

As the ears of a baby are much more sensitive then ours i would recommend to lower your voice way saying/reciting the adhan in the right ear, the iqamah (supposing this is regarded as a good deed) should be recited in the left ear.

These are the most reliable ahadith about the adhan for the new born from [sunan abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/333) and [Jami' at-Timrdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/19/25).

---

And as an addition one could also follow the sunnah by feeding the new born with [softened dates](http://sunnah.com/muslim/38/27). This could be done by one of the parents.

---

Mostly it's the father who recites the adhan in the ear of the new born, but in some customs/traditions it's the grandfather (maternal), as we can read from the referenced ahadith our Messenger () did so for al-Hassan ibn 'Ali ()