# Ahadith reports of the Prophet Muhammad() giving the Adhan or Iqamah himself

Tags: salat, hadith, prophet-muhammad, adhan

I would like to know all the ahadith where it is reported that Prophet had himself given the Adhan or Iqamah.
I did find some [here](http://www.understanding-islam.com/did-the-prophet-pbuh-ever-recite-adan-call-to-prayer/)

Comment: My answer on [How to give adhan in newborn babys ear](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28788/how-to-give-adhan-in-newborn-babys-ear/28792#28792) provides such an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a few examples:

- > They were with the Prophet (S) on a journey. They wound up in a narrow area when Salat became due. Then it began raining from the sky above them, and it was wet beneath them. **So Allah's Messenger (S) called the Adhan** while he was on his mount, and **then the Iqamah**, going forward on his mount. He let them in Salat by making gestures, making his prostrations lower than his bowing. ([Jami' at-Tirmdihi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/264))

This hadith has been qualified as da'if by many scholars among them ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani -who was quoted [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=742&bk_no=56&flag=1) by al-Mubarakpuri in his Tohfat al-Ahwadi تحفة الأحوذي- , at-Tirmidhi himself, ibn al-'Araby, al-Bayhaqi and others, while an-Nawawi (according to ibn Hajar erred) and considered it Hassan. Note that ibn Hajar added that it was narrated by imam Ahmad with the small but meaningful difference that Bilal -not our prophet()- called for the prayer, which means that he would also have made the iqamah!

- > I saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) uttering the call to prayer (Adhan) in the ear of al-Hasan ibn Ali when Fatimah gave birth to him.
  > ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/333) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/19/25), [al-Mustadrak](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=74&bookhad=4694) of al-Hakim from Nishapur, [as-Sunan al-Kubra](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=71&bookhad=18707) of al-Bayhaqi; [Mosnaf](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=73&bookhad=7634) abd ar-Razaaq ...)

Again this hadith is rather da'if as all narrator chains include 'Asim ibn 'Obayd Allah who is not trustworthy and even rejected according the view of most scholars, so qualifying it as-Sahih ghareeb as at-Tirmidhi did is ijtihad and has no backup in the view of scholars of this art.

There's even a worse (in context of weakness) narration of this even quoted by al-Bayhaqi in his sho'ab al-Iman.

Actually most scholar say that none of the ahadith quoting that the prophet () performed the call for adhan or iqamah  himself has a basis. Some explained it saying as if he () would have called for the prayer those who failed to answer would be punished according to:

> ... So let those beware who dissent from the Prophet's order, lest fitnah strike them or a painful punishment. ([24:63](https://legacy.quran.com/24/63))